# Design a simple task scheduler in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I want implement a simple task scheduler in c++ which will support the following:

1. Scheduler will have public function: "add_task(time_ms, func)"
   (The Scheduler will run the function in X milliseconds from now).
2. Support multi-threaded ==> meaning different threads might call add_task in
   parallel with different and provide different time for scheduling.

The main problem here that calls to execute tasks might no be in the right execute order so, maybe the first task will called to run in 6 seconds from now and after 1 second another call will be to execute a task in 2 seconds from now.

In such case I expect the scheduler will cancel the old timer for 6 seconds (that already pass 1 second) and will schedule the second call for 2 seconds from now as it need to be executed first.

I guess I will have to use a priority queue or a map to order my tasks call,

**My question is:** What is the best way to design it?
What units should be involved, how many threads should be involved?
Who responsible for what?
I don't need coding at all, more about the design.

**Here is a simple example for what I mean:**

```
auto func1 = []() { std::cout<<"Task1 is running"<<std::endl;};
auto func2 = []() { std::cout<<"Task2 is running"<<std::endl;};
auto func3 = []() { std::cout<<"Task3 is running"<<std::endl;};

add_task(6000, func1);
this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
add_task(2000, func2);
this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
add_task(3000, func3);
```

**Expected output will be:**

```
Task2 is running
Task3 is running
Task1 is running
```

**Explanation of expected output:**

```
Task2 is running   ==> After 3000ms (1000ms sleep + 2000ms task scheduling)
Task3 is running   ==> After 5000ms (1000ms sleep + 1000ms sleep + 3000ms task scheduling)
Task1 is running   ==> After 6000ms (6000ms task scheduling)
```

Comment: Why, everyone knows that the best way to design something like this would be by working closely [with your own personal rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a piority queue data structure. Where each call to `add_task` inserts an element to the p-queue changing their order by the given time in miliseconds (key). Collect all the task and when running all the tasks you just have to pop out the top element in a available thread at given time.

Comment: My problem is not how to get the tasks ordered, both Priority queue and map able to help me get tasks ordered by time, the question how do I design it to support multi-threaded application which the current top (first) scheduled task might not be eventually the first executed task as in the meantime there might be other task with shorter scheduling time that might be called.

Comment: @ol202020, In one approach, the "scheduler" has a single worker thread that waits on a condition variable with a timeout. It calculates the timeout value so that if the condition is _not_ notified, then the `wait()` call will time out at the exact moment when the next task is due.  The `add_task(t)` method notifies the same condition variable, awakening the worker thread, if the new task `t` becomes the new head of the priority queue (i.e., if the new task `t` is due sooner than the one that the worker was waiting for.)

Comment: Thanks Solomon, this is a good idea what you have suggest.
I was able to implement quickly, thanks a lot!